# I want to use conditional formatting based on two conditions

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I want to use conditional formatting based on two conditions. I want to maintain a bill tracker where I want to highlight duplicate invoice number in column B of a particular vendor in column D. I can't understand how to arrange these formulas on google spreedsheets or in Excel.

Comment: Maybe you can share an example spreadsheet? It will be much easy to understand it?

Answer (score 0):

This formula may help you:

```
=IF(D2="XYZ",IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$15,"XYZ",$A$2:$A$15,A2)>1,TRUE,FALSE),FALSE)
```

See the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Here `XYZ` is specified vendor in column d. Let me know if need any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use just the countifs formula. All with the assumption that you only want to highlight the duplicates of one vendor and not duplicate numbers in general.

```
=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$10;$B2;$D$2:$D$10;$D2)>1
```

And according to your preference you can then format either just the invoice numbers, number and vendor or the entire row.

```
=$B$2:$B$10    
=$B$2:$B$10;$D$2:$D$10
=$B$2:$D$10
```